# iPhone: How can I add a currency symbol, decimal point and decimal places in shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I've found the code below, which I'm trying to make work in the UITableView shouldChangeCharactersInRange event. Without the currency symbol it works fine.

When I try to add the currency symbol, it just allows me to enter one number. What it should do is this, say I enter 7536, it should appear in the following steps £0.07, £0.75, £7.53, £75.36  but instead it appears as £0.07, £0.05, £0.03, £0.06

Heres the code.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
        shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
        replacementString:(NSString *)string
{    BOOL res = TRUE;

    double currentValue = [textField.text doubleValue];
    double cents = round(currentValue * 100.0f);

    if ([string length]) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if (isnumber(c)) {
                cents *= 10;
                cents += c - '0'; 
            }            
        }
    } else {
        // back Space
        cents = floor(cents / 10);
    }

    // This line next works without the currency symbol
    //textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", cents / 100.0f];

    NSMutableString *aString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strCurrencySymbol];    
    [aString appendFormat:@"%.2f", cents / 100.0f];
    textField.text = aString;

    res = NO;
return res;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    NSCharacterSet *currencySet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"$€£¥"];
    NSMutableString *strSource = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textField.text];
    if (![strSource isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [strSource replaceCharactersInRange: [strSource rangeOfCharacterFromSet:currencySet]  withString:@""];
    }

    double currentValue = [strSource doubleValue];
    double cents = round(currentValue * 100.0f);

    if ([string length]) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if (isnumber(c)) {
                cents *= 10;
                cents += c - '0'; 
            }            
        }
    } else {
        // back Space
        cents = floor(cents / 10);
    }

    NSMutableString *aString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strCurrencySymbol];    // does not need to be released. Needs to be retained if you need to keep use it after the current function.
    switch (intDecimalPlaces) {
        case 0:
            [aString appendFormat:@"%.0f", cents / 100.0f];
            break;
        case 1:
            [aString appendFormat:@"%.1f", cents / 100.0f];
            break;
        case 2:
            [aString appendFormat:@"%.2f", cents / 100.0f];
            break;
        case 3:
            [aString appendFormat:@"%.3f", cents / 100.0f];             
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    textField.text = aString;
```

I forgot to remove the currency symbol at the start.
Then you add it at the end without problem.

Answer (score 0):

`[@"£1.23" doubleValue]` is 0. You have to skip over a leading currency symbol if there is one, something like:

```
NSString * currentText = textField.text;
NSRange range = [currentText rangeOfString:strCurrencySymbol];
if (range.location == 0)
{
  currentText = [currentText substringFromIndex:range.length];
}
double currentValue = [currentText doubleValue];
```

In general, I'd advise against doing stuff like this:

- It might not work with all input methods (and IIRC shouldChangeCharactersInRange: isn't called for autocompletions).
- It doesn't seem user-friendly, unless you work at a cash register (where they have a "00" key because otherwise entering "$100.00" is a pain). I want to be able to enter "1" and mean $1.00
- It's not localized.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand can you give me the full shouldChangeCharactersInRange function. I'm not going to enable auto completion. Also, I doubt $100.00 will be entered very often. I'm going to pass in different currency symbols and decimal places.

Comment: You need to strip the currency symbol before calling `-doubleValue` to get `currentValue`. My code does this. The rest of your code can follow.

Comment: The value at the start won't have a currency symbol, the whole point is that I want to add it and show it after each keypress. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: You add it to textField.text, so the next time you read from textField.text you need to remove it before parsing it as a double. ARGH.